# To split Strings from a MultiAutoCompleteTextView and set it to different textview

Tags: android, textview, multiautocompletetextview

I have a array of strings which is a resultant of options selected from a MultiAutoCompleteTextView using the comma tokenizer. The string appears as below:
"India, China, Japan, America, Australia"

I need to seperate this values based on the coma positiona and set those values to different textview's. Also I need to restrict the users to select only 5 values and those values should not be repeated.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please mention how can I restrict user from selecting the same option repeatedly. (ie) if an user firsts selects India, then he should not be able to select that option again, even if he selects the India again, the user should be notified regarding that through an toast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `String.split()` like this:

```
String[] array = yourString.split(",");
```

And iterate through that array.

EDIT:

To check if the user already selected the item, you can add an `OnItemClickListener` to your `multiAutoCompleteTextView` and have a `HashSet` or a `Set` where your items clicked are stored and check if this item already exists in the set

Example:

Initialize your `HashSet` first: `HashSet<String> hashset = new HashSet<String>();`

And later:

```
youMultiAutoCompleteTv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            String itemClicked = parent.getAdapter().getItem(position).toString();
            if(hashset.contains(itemClicked)){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Item exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else {
                hashset.add(itemClicked);
            }


        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please mention how can I restrict user from selecting the same option repeatedly. (ie) if an user firsts selects India, then he should not be able to select that option again, even if he selects the India again, the user should be notified regarding that through an toast.

Comment: Hi, in this case the user is notified with a toast that they have selected the same option. Though the duplicate value is not added to the hashset, still it is visible in the editable text of MultiautocompleteTextView. Can you please mention how I can delete it...?
it appears as in this link: http://prntscr.com/75hfbs 

Can you please mention how I can delete the repeated item?

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this:

```
String myListAsString = "India, China, Japan, America, Australia";
String[] countries = myListAsString.split(",");
TextView t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.t1);
TextView t2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.t2);
TextView t3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.t3);
TextView t4 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.t4);
TextView t5 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.t5);
t1.setText(countries[0]);
t2.setText(countries[1]);
t3.setText(countries[2]);
t4.setText(countries[3]);
t5.setText(countries[4]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please mention how can I restrict user from selecting the same option repeatedly. (ie) if an user firsts selects India, then he should not be able to select that option again, even if he selects the India again, the user should be notified regarding that through an toast.

Comment: What kind of views are your options that could be selected? Maybe it could be an onClick event on the current option view

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
   String input = editText.getText().toString().trim(); //Getting String from view.

   String[] singleInputs = input.split("\\s*,\\s*"); //Splitting in proper way.
```